# Regex to match first occurrence of non alpha-numeric characters

Tags: python, regex

I am parsing some user input to make a basic Discord bot assigning roles and such. I am trying to generalize some code to reuse for different similar tasks (doing similar things in different categories/channels).

Generally, I am looking for a substring (the category), then taking the string after as that categories value. I am looking line by line for my category, replacing the "category" substring and returning a stripped version. However, what I have now also replaces any space in the "value" string.

Originally the string looks like this:

```
Gamertag : 00test gamertag
```

What I want to do, is preserve the spaces in the value. The regex I am trying to do is: match all non alpha-numeric chars until the first letter.

My return is already matching non alpha but can't figure out how to get just first group, looks like it should be simply adding a ? to make it a lazy operator but not sure.. example code and string below (regex I want to replace is the final print string).

String I am working with:

```
- 00test Gamertag      #(or any non-alpha delimiter)
```

Desired Results   (by matching and stripping the extra characters)

```
00test Gamertag     #(remove leading space and any non-alpha characters before the first words)
```

The regex I am trying to do is: match all non alpha-numeric chars until the first letter. Should be something like the following, which is close to what I use to strip non-alphas now but it does all not the first group - so I want to match the first group of non-alphas in a string to strip that part using re.sub..

```
\W+?
```

https://www.online-python.com/gDVhZrnmlq

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just `split(' - ')`?

Comment: The delimiter and spacing is not always the same, the example is just one general example

Comment: You mean by _get just first group_ getting just the first word, like 00test for `- 00test Gamertag`?

Comment: No, actually I guess I am using the regex opposite of how I explained. I am matching what I want to remove and then splitting on that. So I am trying to match the first group of non alpha characters to remove them with re.sub. In this case there is a " - " delimiter, but sometimes it is also just spaces in front. And I am trying to preserve the space in the string.

Comment: Actually, I don't understand the problem. What is wrong with the output you get with your program?

Comment: @trincot , what do you mean gamer_tag should be assigned once from line.replace to get the "value" string from that line and then last step is where I want to strip non-alphas and return the string. It is also set to = "" in the beginning.

Comment: Is `^\W+` what you are looking for?

Comment: @trincot yes that is exactly what I was looking for! If you want to post as an answer I will give you credit since you posted first and exactly what I was asking for. (shoutout sweepy with another good answer though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex will substitute the non-alphanumerical characters *anywhere* in the input string. If you only need to have this happening at the *start* of the string, then use the start-of-input anchor (i.e. `^`):

```
^\W+
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thanks, thought I needed to use a lazy operator to select only the first match.. Regex is a real struggle, but like magic how much you can do with one line of it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your inputs, you can use two regex to achieve your goal, the first to remove all non alpha-numeric from your string including the ones between words, and the second one to remove whitespaces between words if there is more than one space between each two words :

```
import re


gamer_tag = "µ& - 00test          -   Gamertag"
gamer_tag = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]", "", gamer_tag)
gamer_tag = re.sub(r" +", " ", gamer_tag)
print(gamer_tag.strip())

# Output: 00test Gamertag
```

You can remove the second `re.sub()` if you sure that there will no more than one space between words.

```
gamer_tag = "- 00test Gamertag "
gamer_tag = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]", "", gamer_tag)
print(gamer_tag.strip())

# Output: 00test Gamertag
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Looks to do what I asked, though not exactly using regex grouping like I was trying to get at.. Gave trincot the answer credit cause they responded with the exact regex first.. Appreciate your help though!